# Identify if guest sharing is enabled in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, modern-experience, guest-access

I tried using `context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.guestsEnabled`, but it returns false when external sharing on the site is set to "Existing guests only" and works fine for "New and Existing Guests".

[image]

Is there any other way to know if guest access is enabled on the site in SPFx?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of `legacyPageContext` object.

> Also, I would like to highlight another point that, this property "this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.guestsEnabled" returns **FALSE** when we choose **Existing Guests only** Option in Admin for external sharing.
>
> However, if I choose the **New and Existing Guests** option it returns **TRUE**, I was expecting **TRUE** for both the selections.

**Source**: [Identifying External Sharing in Site Collections using SPFx](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/5250)

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.